# What URL should I use?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I wrote an app some time ago, and now I need to use push notifications. I used `Firebase` to receive notifications; so far, so good.

Now, I need the admin version of my app to be able to create those notifications, instead of sending them via the console. [This documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server) says that I should create a `POST`request, but it doesn't explain what URL I sould POST to.

What is the URL to use?

Comment: "To send a message, the application server issues a POST request. For example:

https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send " did you not read that part, or is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at:

[Sending downstream messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream)

POST REQUEST:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

to is the device key.
Autorization header is your FCM key.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I thought my app's name should be somewhere in the url. However, that is to send to ONE device. How can I send a notification to _all_ devices?

Comment: I don't know if there's a "magic" way to send broadcast messages, probably don't. You will have to do a post request to each device.

Answer (score 1):

To send notification like the firebase console, make POST request like this

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA  

{
   "to" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
   "notification" : {
       "body" : "great match!",
       "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
       "icon" : "myicon"
    }
 }
```

it's important to use "notification" as a keyword

see this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options